# Force PS3 clone arcade gamepad to be hid generic

Tags: usb, raspberry-pi, hid, joystick

I have a NETWAY GAMING ARCADE FIGHTER PS3/PC. This device works fine under windows and also does on recalbox 4.1, but does not in any current linux that I have tried.

I have tried to recompile hid-sony with various older versions, including the very same that works on recalbox 4.1 (v4.4.13). When using that version in recent ubuntu it seems to improve detection but it still fails.

Here are the logs of the device:

```
RECALBOX user.info kernel: [  99.858844] usb 1-1.4: new full-speed USB device number 5 using dwc_otg
RECALBOX user.info kernel: [  99.980280] usb 1-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=054c, idProduct=0268
RECALBOX user.info kernel: [  99.980789] usb 1-1.4: Mew USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNunmber=0
RECALBOX user.info kernel: [  99.960296] usb 1-1.4: Product: USB Controller
RECALBOX user.info kernel: [ 100.135534] usb 1-1.4: USB disconnect, device number 5
RECALBOX user.info kernel: [ 100.135955] input: USB Controller as /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1—1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/0003:054C:0268.0003/input/input2
RECALBOX user.info kernel: [ 100.136001] sony 0003:054C:0268.0003: input,hiddev0,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Joystick [USB Controller! on ush—3f980000.usb—1.4/input0
RECALBOX user.err kernel:  [ 100.136022] sony 0003:054C:0268.0003: can’t set operational mode: step 1
RECALBOX user.info kernel: [ 101.138844] usb 1-1.4: new full-speed USB device number 6 using dwc_otg
RECALBOX user.info kernel: [ 101.253950] usb 1-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=1345, idProduct=3008
RECALBOX user.info kernel: [ 101.253959] usb 1-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
RECALBOX user.info kernel: [ 101.253965] usb 1-1.4: Product: USB Controller
RECALBOX user.info kernel: [ 101.275011] input: USB Controller as /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/0003:1345:3008.0004/input/input3
RECALBOX user.info kernel: [ 101.275358] hid-generic 0003:1345:3008.0004: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Gamepad [USB Controller] on usb—3f980000.usb—1.4/inputO
```

(recalbox 4.1, working)

```
ubuntu kernel: [ 4639.424468] usb 1-8: new full-speed USB device number 32 using xhci_hcd
ubuntu kernel: [ 4639.758139] usb 1-8: New USB device found, idVendor=054c, idProduct=0268, bcdDevice= 1.00
ubuntu kernel: [ 4639.758142] usb 1-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
ubuntu kernel: [ 4639.758145] usb 1-8: Product: USB Controller
ubuntu kernel: [ 4639.919303] sony 0003:054C:0268.0023: failed to retrieve feature report 0xf2 with the Sixaxis MAC address
ubuntu kernel: [ 4639.919558] sony 0003:054C:0268.0023: hiddev3,hidraw5: USB HID v81.11 Joystick [USB Controller] on usb-0000:15:00.0-8/input0
ubuntu kernel: [ 4639.919560] sony 0003:054C:0268.0023: failed to claim input
ubuntu kernel: [ 4639.919678] usb 1-8: USB disconnect, device number 32
ubuntu kernel: [ 4640.892687] usb 1-8: new full-speed USB device number 33 using xhci_hcd
ubuntu kernel: [ 4641.225377] usb 1-8: New USB device found, idVendor=1345, idProduct=3008, bcdDevice= 1.00
ubuntu kernel: [ 4641.225381] usb 1-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
ubuntu kernel: [ 4641.225383] usb 1-8: Product: USB Controller
ubuntu kernel: [ 4641.252351] sony 0003:1345:3008.0024: failed to retrieve feature report 0xf2 with the Sixaxis MAC address
ubuntu kernel: [ 4641.252760] sony 0003:1345:3008.0024: hiddev4,hidraw6: USB HID v81.10 Gamepad [USB Controller] on usb-0000:15:00.0-8/input0
ubuntu kernel: [ 4641.252762] sony 0003:1345:3008.0024: failed to claim input
```

(ubuntu 18.10 default module, not working)

```
ubuntu kernel: [20957.230577] usb 1-9: new full-speed USB device number 14 using xhci_hcd
ubuntu kernel: [20957.563354] usb 1-9: New USB device found, idVendor=054c, idProduct=0268, bcdDevice= 1.00
ubuntu kernel: [20957.563358] usb 1-9: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
ubuntu kernel: [20957.563360] usb 1-9: Product: USB Controller
ubuntu kernel: [20957.597896] input: USB Controller as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:15:00.0/usb1/1-9/1-9:1.0/0003:054C:0268.000D/input/input27
ubuntu kernel: [20957.598255] sony 0003:054C:0268.000D: input,hiddev1,hidraw3: USB HID v1.11 Joystick [USB Controller] on usb-0000:15:00.0-9/input0
ubuntu kernel: [20957.724424] sony 0003:054C:0268.000D: can't set operational mode: step 1
ubuntu kernel: [20957.810926] sony: probe of 0003:054C:0268.000D failed with error -71
ubuntu kernel: [20957.811129] usb 1-9: USB disconnect, device number 14
ubuntu kernel: [20958.702612] usb 1-9: new full-speed USB device number 15 using xhci_hcd
ubuntu kernel: [20959.033593] usb 1-9: New USB device found, idVendor=1345, idProduct=3008, bcdDevice= 1.00
ubuntu kernel: [20959.033597] usb 1-9: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
ubuntu kernel: [20959.033599] usb 1-9: Product: USB Controller
```

(ubuntu 18.10 module v4.4.13, not working)

```
Bus 001 Device 035: ID 1345:3008 Sino Lite Technology Corp. 
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0         8
  idVendor           0x1345 Sino Lite Technology Corp.
  idProduct          0x3008 
  bcdDevice            1.00
  iManufacturer           0 
  iProduct                2 
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           34
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              500mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 No Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 None
      iInterface              0 
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.10
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength     112
         Report Descriptors: 
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval              10
```

(lsusb -v)

What I can notice is that with recalbox the device is finally managed by hid-generic, however with the same version of hid-sony compiled for ubuntu it does not trigger hid-generic and fails with hid-sony.

Is there a way to force it to be managed by hid-generic instead of hid-sony as seems to happen with recalbox? May be via some usb quirk?

**Update:**

I think this patch is what makes the difference between working in recalbox 4.1 and not working in ubuntu with the same hid-sony.c driver version.

https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/8026101/

It looks to me that since the addition of

```
#define USB_VENDOR_ID_SINO_LITE             0x1345
#define USB_DEVICE_ID_SINO_LITE_CONTROLLER  0x3008
```

the gamepad is managed by hid-sony.c, as hid-core.c does check for hid_have_special_driver and the vendor/device combo matches.

So besides recompiling the whole kernel with the device identifier for my device replaced, are there other solutions?

Can I make the gamepad report a different device id to the os using hid quirks or udev perhaps?

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: The very first log line for the one that works says 'using dwc_otg' whereas the other two say 'using xhci_hcd'. I would start by looking into that.

Comment: The dwc_otg driver is the driver for the USB controller built into the Raspberry Pi. I did not mention that the recalbox os was running on raspberry pi.

Comment: Ok. It's probably worth adding the raspberry-pi tag then, as that could be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that the **hid** module has the paramenter **ignore_special_drivers** which does just that, ignore all the specialized drivers and use hid-generic to handle the device.

Since the hid-sony module does not support properly my PS3 clone arcade stick, adding the parameter to hid module solves the issue.

```
$ sudo vi /etc/modprobe.d/hid.conf
options hid ignore_special_drivers=1

$ sudo update-initramfs -u
$ reboot
$ tail /var/log/kern.log
ubuntu kernel: [  119.966133] usb 1-8: new full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
ubuntu kernel: [  120.299429] usb 1-8: New USB device found, idVendor=054c, idProduct=0268, bcdDevice= 1.00
ubuntu kernel: [  120.299433] usb 1-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
ubuntu kernel: [  120.299435] usb 1-8: Product: USB Controller
ubuntu kernel: [  120.333900] input: USB Controller as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:15:00.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/0003:054C:0268.0004/input/input18
ubuntu kernel: [  120.334403] hid-generic 0003:054C:0268.0004: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.11 Joystick [USB Controller] on usb-0000:15:00.0-8/input0
ubuntu kernel: [  120.459845] usb 1-8: USB disconnect, device number 5
ubuntu kernel: [  121.434688] usb 1-8: new full-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
ubuntu kernel: [  121.765665] usb 1-8: New USB device found, idVendor=1345, idProduct=3008, bcdDevice= 1.00
ubuntu kernel: [  121.765669] usb 1-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
ubuntu kernel: [  121.765671] usb 1-8: Product: USB Controller
ubuntu kernel: [  121.791046] input: USB Controller as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:15:00.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/0003:1345:3008.0005/input/input19
ubuntu kernel: [  121.851274] hid-generic 0003:1345:3008.0005: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.10 Gamepad [USB Controller] on usb-0000:15:00.0-8/input0
```

Still I would prefer a solution that allows to ignore the special driver only for the specific VendorID/ProductID combo in the event I had an original sony game controller and wanted to use both.

Comment: You should be able to customize Udev (i.e. by using udev rules) to block the sony driver just for one particular piece of hardware.

Comment: I tried blacklisting hid-sony module all together but that does not work at all, as it does not bounce back to hid-generic and the device is not claimed.